# the function and use of cell(m,n) in matlab

Tags: matlab

I was reading that in MatLab, if you are going to fill a larger matrix, its more computational efficient to declare it's size from before with the use of the cell command; E.g.

```
X = cell(500,90);
```

but when I try to add values to it, like

```
X(i;) = x
```

where i is vector of double of length 90, and i an integer, I get

`conversion from cell to double is not possible`

Is my understanding of the cell function correct?

Comment: i think you've confused [cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br1xnp2-1.html) with something else. Use `zeros` instead.

Comment: Thank you Rasman!! Now seeing your comment! You are absolutely correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell contents are being addressed using curly braces, for example:

```
X{1,1}=1:8;
```

`cell` command creates an empty array:

```
C = cell(3,4,2);
% Or alternatively:
C{3,4,2} = [];
```

What you do with the `cell array` is up to you. But *most likely* it is not what you want - see [Rasman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/666596/rasman) comment.

Have a look at some more examples either at [MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html) or [other tutorials](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/matlab_prog/Cell_Arrys.html).

Comment: Did some digging up, notice it is probably easier to just declare an all zero matrix. Thanks alot!